# Convert all the columns of a spark dataframe into a json format and then include the json formatted data as a column in another/parent dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Converted dataframe(say child dataframe) into json using df.toJSON

After json conversion the schema looks like this :

```
root
 |-- value: string (nullable = true)
```

I used the following suggestion to get child dataframe into the intermediate parent schema/dataframe:

```
scala> parentDF.toJSON.select(struct($"value").as("data")).printSchema
root
 |-- data: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |-- value: string (nullable = true)
```

Now I still need to build the parentDF schema further to make it look like:

```
root
 |-- id
 |-- version 
 |-- data: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |-- value: string (nullable = true)
```

Q1) How can I build the id column using the id from value(i.e value.id needs to be represented as id)

Q2) I need to bring version from a different dataframe(say versionDF) where version is a constant(in all columns). Do I fetch one row from this versionDF to read value of version column and then populate it as literal in the parentDF ?

please help with any code snippets on this.

Comment: Can you add parentdf schema ? And add expected output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `toJSON` use `to_json` in `select` statement & select required columns along with `to_json` function.

Check below code.

```
val version =  // Get version value from versionDF
parentDF.select($"id",struct(to_json(struct($"*")).as("value")).as("data"),lit(version).as("version"))

scala> parentDF.select($"id",struct(to_json(struct($"*")).as("value")).as("data"),lit(version).as("version")).printSchema
root
 |-- id: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- data: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |-- value: string (nullable = true)
 |-- version: double (nullable = false)
```

**Updated**

```
scala> df.select($"id",to_json(struct(struct($"*").as("value"))).as("data"),lit(version).as("version")).printSchema
root
 |-- id: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- data: string (nullable = true)
 |-- version: integer (nullable = false)


scala> df.select($"id",to_json(struct(struct($"*").as("value"))).as("data"),lit(version).as("version")).show(false)
+---+------------------------------------------+-------+
|id |data                                      |version|
+---+------------------------------------------+-------+
|1  |{"value":{"id":1,"col1":"a1","col2":"b1"}}|1      |
|2  |{"value":{"id":2,"col1":"a2","col2":"b2"}}|1      |
|3  |{"value":{"id":3,"col1":"a3","col2":"b3"}}|1      |
+---+------------------------------------------+-------+
```

**Update-1**

```
scala> df.select($"id",to_json(struct($"*").as("value")).as("data"),lit(version).as("version")).printSchema
root
 |-- id: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- data: string (nullable = true)
 |-- version: integer (nullable = false)


scala> df.select($"id",to_json(struct($"*").as("value")).as("data"),lit(version).as("version")).show(false)
+---+--------------------------------+-------+
|id |data                            |version|
+---+--------------------------------+-------+
|1  |{"id":1,"col1":"a1","col2":"b1"}|1      |
|2  |{"id":2,"col1":"a2","col2":"b2"}|1      |
|3  |{"id":3,"col1":"a3","col2":"b3"}|1      |
+---+--------------------------------+-------+
```

Comment: This approach is good. However when i access the 'data' I see a jsonarray enclosure. need the data as jsonobject. is there a code adjustment which will achieve the same.

Comment: can you please output how it is coming &  how you want ?

Comment: Current content of data looks like this  : 
[{"id":1,"col1":"a1","col2":"b1"}]


Expected format of data:

{"id":1,"col1":"a1","col2":"b1"}
NOTE: no [ ] enclosure in the latter one - which is how its expected(jsonobject). Thanks for help.

Comment: Any specific reason why you want object, trying to understand problem ??

Comment: It is more of a requirement for this program and also it is natural(I think) to have data represented in jsonobject format by default. jsonarray represents more like a collection of jsonobjects - and 'data' field here is just a json object.

Comment: One reason why you are seeing array is you asked move value one level down to data field. if you want only object you can directly use value

Comment: is it not possible to have data contain a nested jsonobject ? because that is what I'm looking for.

Comment: you will get data like this - {"value":{"id":1,"cola":"aa","colb":"bb"}} is it ok ??

Comment: ideally 'data' should be {"id":1,"cola":"aa","colb":"bb"}. feel free to add code for your suggestion though.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
scala> val versionDF = List((1.0)).toDF("version")
versionDF: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [version: double]

scala> versionDF.show
+-------+
|version|
+-------+
|    1.0|
+-------+


scala> val version = versionDF.first.get(0)
version: Any = 1.0

scala>

scala> val childDF = List((1,"a1","b1"),(2,"a2","b2"),(3,"a3","b3")).toDF("id","col1","col2")
childDF: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: int, col1: string ... 1 more field]

scala> childDF.show
+---+----+----+
| id|col1|col2|
+---+----+----+
|  1|  a1|  b1|
|  2|  a2|  b2|
|  3|  a3|  b3|
+---+----+----+


scala>

scala> val parentDF =  childDF.toJSON.select(struct($"value").as("data")).withColumn("id",from_json($"data.value",childDF.schema).getItem("id")).withColumn("version",lit(version))
parentDF: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [data: struct<value: string>, id: int ... 1 more field]

scala> parentDF.printSchema
root
 |-- data: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |-- value: string (nullable = true)
 |-- id: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- version: double (nullable = false)

scala> parentDF.show(false)
+----------------------------------+---+-------+
|data                              |id |version|
+----------------------------------+---+-------+
|[{"id":1,"col1":"a1","col2":"b1"}]|1  |1.0    |
|[{"id":2,"col1":"a2","col2":"b2"}]|2  |1.0    |
|[{"id":3,"col1":"a3","col2":"b3"}]|3  |1.0    |
+----------------------------------+---+-------+
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. 
why is the data being reflected as jsonarray when we perform a toJSON or to_json. any way we can get the 'data' represented a jsonobject ?

Comment: `struct` function makes it look like array. 
e.g.
'childDF.select(struct(lit("col1val"),lit("col2val")).as("structColumn")).show
|      structColumn|
+------------------+
|[col1val, col2val]|'
If you dont want it, just use below:
`childDF.toJSON.withColumnRenamed("value","data").show(false)

+--------------------------------+
|data                            |
+--------------------------------+
|{"id":1,"col1":"a1","col2":"b1"}|
|{"id":2,"col1":"a2","col2":"b2"}|
|{"id":3,"col1":"a3","col2":"b3"}|
+--------------------------------+`