# How can i send my structured streaming dataframe to kafka?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming, spark-kafka-integration

**Hello everyone !**

I'm trying to send my structured streaming dataframe to one of my kafka topics, `detection`.

This is the schema of the structued streaming dataframe:

```
 root
 |-- timestamp: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- Sigma: string (nullable = true)
 |-- time: string (nullable = true)
 |-- duration: string (nullable = true)
 |-- SourceComputer: string (nullable = true)
 |-- SourcePort: string (nullable = true)
 |-- DestinationComputer: string (nullable = true)
 |-- DestinationPort: string (nullable = false)
 |-- protocol: string (nullable = true)
 |-- packetCount: string (nullable = true)
 |-- byteCount: string (nullable = true)
```

but then i try to send the dataframe, with this method:

```
dfwriter=df \
  .selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)") \
  .writeStream \
  .format("kafka") \
  .option("checkpointLocation", "/Documents/checkpoint/logs") \
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092") \
  .option("failOnDataLoss", "false") \
  .option("topic", detection) \
  .start()
```

Then i got the error :

**pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`value`' given input columns: [DestinationComputer, DestinationPort, Sigma, SourceComputer, SourcePort, byteCount, duration, packetCount, processName, protocol, time, timestamp]; line 1 pos 5;**

If i send a dataframe with juste the column `value` it works, i receive the data on my kafka topic consumer.

*Any idea to send my dataframe with all columns ?*

Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your dataframe has no `value` column, as the error says.

You'd need to "embed" all columns under a `value` `StructType` column, then use a function like `to_json`, not `CAST( .. AS STRING)`

In Pyspark, that'd be something like `struct(to_json(struct($"*")).as("value")` within a select query

Similar question - [Convert all the columns of a spark dataframe into a json format and then include the json formatted data as a column in another/parent dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62162293/convert-all-the-columns-of-a-spark-dataframe-into-a-json-format-and-then-include)

Comment: Thank you, if F is my dataframe, this is how i did it in pyspark: **F=F.select(to_json(struct(F.schema.names)).alias('value'))**

Comment: Btw, if you want the timestamp to be the Kafka record timestamp and not part of the message value, you can select that separately as well